# ASP.NET MVC Inproc session mode not storing session data on windows server 2019 datacenter version

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session-state

Recently I have faced a very weird issue with ASP.NET MVC **Inproc** session mode. I have a web application that stores user data (username, role, etc) within the session so that it can be accessed throughout the application lifecycle.
The application works perfectly fine on my local system, and on the UAT environment, but the same application deployed on production(Server provided by client) is not storing the session data. As soon as I log in to the application, session data is lost due to which session variable storing the user data becomes null. I have also tried increasing the session time out.

I have tried everything I could, I assume this can be due to some server configuration that might be restricting the worker process or forcing it to recycle. But I am not so good at infrastructure-related things, so any help could be appreciated!

Comment: Is it one production server? Is that production server behind some firewall? Are all cookies passed to the server and not stripped from your call upstream?

Comment: You have a Front End and Back End.  It looks like the Back End is failing.  there is probably something wrong with Roles.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-security/roles/creating-and-managing-roles-cs?force_isolation=trueSee :    You could also have a connection string issue between the server and backend database.

Comment: Yes, there's one production server. Cookies are received at client side, but validation of cookie fails as the server is not able to maintain the matching pair on server (IIS worker process) - rene

Comment: I am connecting the web application with API(Comprises of swagger). I have tested the functionality of API by posting data via swagger, am getting valid response as well. Also if I pass wrong username and password combination, I am getting the response as invalid credentials. But when I pass a valid credentials it doesn't show's any message, but username text becomes null. It shows, welcome only instead of welcome username. @jdweng

Comment: Maybe one of these applies to your production server: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/aspnet/session-data-lost-inproc-mode

Comment: I tried the troubleshoot method specified, but no luck. So, I have changed session mode from Inproc to State server. Anyways thanks for your help.  @rene